# GitHub - Enabling "comment" events / error: unable to process webhook

Tags: github, continuous-integration, webhooks, github-api, continuous-deployment

In my repository I am trying to configure a webhook which gets triggered whenever a (pull request) `comment` event is issued. However, when I test that functionality I keep seeing an error

```
{"error":"unable to process webhook: <repo_name> does not have comment events enabled"}
```

whenever I inspect *Recent Deliveries* under *Webhooks / Manage webhook* page.

Question: How can I enable `comment` events for my repository?
Note that the error persists even if I select *Send me everything* under *Which events would you like to trigger this webhook?*

Answer (score 2):

I'll post an answer to my own question, in case someone comes across a similar problem in the future. The issue was solved by:

1. Enabling `comment` Webhook event for the repository in the CI service dashboard (as opposed to configuring repository settings in GitHub)
2. Enabling an `Issue comment` event in the GitHub webhooks settings (when a PR comment is made, apparently an `Issue comment` event is triggered and not `Pull request review comment`).

Comment: The "Issue comment" web hook was the missing piece I had been looking for in trying to trigger a build using the `issueCommentTrigger` from the Jenkins [Pipeline: GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin#issuecommenttrigger) plugin.